# SQL server report builder 3.0 dynamic grouping and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

So I'm trying to make a report and I want to group my row using certain condition.
This is what I have

```
    Code    July,1    July,2  SC   BF
    20       5          2      1    6
    21       4          1      4    1
    31       4          7      9    2
    35       5          1      6    0
```

What I want to do is sum for the twenties, thirties and etc. like

```
    Code    July,1    July,2  SC   BF
    20       5          2      1    6
    21       4          1      4    1
    2*       9          3      5    7
    31       4          7      9    2
    35       5          1      6    0
    3*       9          8      15   2
```

Or possibly

```
    Code    July,1    July,2  SC   BF
    20       5          2      1    6
    21       4          1      4    1
    2*                         5    7
    31       4          7      9    2
    35       5          1      6    0
    3*                         15   2
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ssrs report You can add a calculated field in your dataset  with field name as Group and expression as `=Floor(Fields!code.Value/10)` and then in tablix do your sum bassed on that grouping.
[image: Adding Expression]

[image: Creating Tablix]

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you so much. That helps alot

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is in your SQL setup a column you can group by.  In this case if Code is an integer, you can divide by 10 and it will group all the twenties with 2 and thirties with 3:

```
create table #test
(
    intValue int,
    sumValue int
)

insert into #test
select 20, 9
union all select 21, 10
union all select 30, 1
union all select 31, 2

select * , round(intValue/10,0) as GroupByThis
from #test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Code    July,1    July,2  SC   BF from tablename
union 



select DISTINCT Code/10 ,  (select SUM (July,1) over (Code/10) from tablename where code=t.code)July,1   ,    (select SUM (July,2) over (Code/10) from tablename where code=t.code) July,2 ,  (select SUM (SC) over (Code/10) from tablename where code=t.code) SC,  (select SUM (BF) over (Code/10) from tablename where code=t.code) BF from tablename t
```